# Covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ or figure-$8$-space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am studying **Algebraic Topology** written by **Allen Hatcher**. In page 58 the author gives some samples of infinitely many varieties of covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ i.e. figure-$8$-space. But I don't find any clear justification in this book as to why all of them are covering spaces of the figure-$8$-space. Also I am very eager to know the generators of such covering spaces mentioned in the same page. How do I justify them? Also how do I find the Galois group of those covering spaces on my own? What is the basic intuition behind that? I have tried to find out lecture notes from online source describing these facts explicitly but I have failed to find any of them. Can anybody help me by giving me some thoughts about that or by giving me some notes available online for free so that I can study them on my own and think independently?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: For your first question, there is no formal proof of this in the book, but is it not clear from the preceding discussion on pg. 57? In the author's terminology, they are clearly all 2-oriented graphs, and the labeling scheme defines for each one an $n$-1 surjection.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with graph theory. I think that is the main reason for which I didn't understand the preceding discussion. Would you please make it clear to me? Then it will help me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to know any graph theory. $S^1\vee S^1$ is the figure eight. This is the figure on page 57, with one vertex (blob) and two edges (loops starting at the blob and ending at the blob), labelled $a$ and $b$. The arrows indicate a chosen, but arbitrary, orientation, which really has no intrinsic meaning here, but is used to define the covering homomorphisms. Now choose your favourite picture on pg 58. It has several vertices, where two or more edges meet. Under the covering homomorphism, all of these vertices are sent to the single blob in the picture on pg. 57.

Comment: Now back in the picture on page 58., each of the edges is either labelled $a$, or $b$, and this corresponds to how they are mapped onto the edges on the figure $8$ on page 58. This is how the covering is defined. For example in picture (4), there are three vertices, three edges $a$, and three edges $b$. This is a 3-sheeted covering. The inverse image of any point in the figure $8$ by the covering homomorphism is a discrete set three points.

Comment: How do I find out generators of the covering spaces as mentioned in this book?

Comment: What do you mean by 'generators' in this context?

Comment: Look at the page 58. The author has written something (in my words generators of the corresponding covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$) in between the symbol $\langle \cdot \rangle$ below each of the diagrams of covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$.

Comment: So if you don't know what 'generator' in this context means, then why do you want to calculate them? I think you might find it helpful to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group